# Integrating trunk revisions with forked Hg project

Tags: mercurial, fork

How do I fork a continually-evolving project to customise for a specific client, while continually pulling improvements from the major branch without losing my customisations?

Should I just keep pulling from the main repository, merging appropriate changes and never push back?

I haven't been using Mercurial long, so I am concerned about integrating the two projects without making a mess of changed namespaces and different domain (client) logic.

---

**Update:** It looks like using separate repositories which pull from a main repository is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're using it:

> Should I just keep pulling from the main repository, merging appropriate changes and never push back?

is precisely my preferred way of handling this.  Any change that applies to multiple customers gets done in the main repo and pulled into the per-customer repos.  Any per-customer changes are done in the per-customer repo and never pushed back to main.

Comment: How do you deal with changed namespaces? I've been developing a project with one company name as the root namespace and now I'd like to generalise it. If I change it, won't that mess up all my pulls?

Comment: Just curious.  Why do you prefer separate repos rather than the named customer branches I mentioned? I've found the multiple repos to be more of a pain than having customer branches, but maybe there is something I'm missing.

Comment: When I started with Mercurial named branches were new and not often recommended. I still don't like that named branches can't ever be deleted. Separate repos work great for me because none of my tools save absolute paths to project files or anything like that -- I understand that some IDEs do which makes separate repos a pain, and I like not having to pick a permanent name to start on something. Bookmarks are probably the best compromise between the two, and as of 1.6 they're pushable. Steve Losh has the best summary of it all http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial

Comment: isn't the what ` --close-branch` since Mercurial 1.2 is for? I've never used it though.

Comment: Close branch hides it in some contexts, but it's never gone.  For example, pushing a closed branch still requires either --force or --new-branch which really confuses some people.  Also the changesets on that branch will forever be on that branch, of course.

Comment: I don't think we have dealt with the changing namespace issue here. In my scenario (C# VS2010) changing namespace changes folder names too. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: If you change the folder name with `hg rename` Mercurial will still associate the old and new names correctly, and changes that affect the old name that are pulled in will be applied to the new names.

Answer (score 0):

We use [named branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Branch#Named_branches).  Make a branch from the default with the customizations and merge the changes from the default into the named branch as needed.